# ExampleData problem

Tags: probability-or-statistics

When running :

`iris = ExampleData[{"MachineLearning", "FisherIris"}, "Data"];`

I get the message :

`MachineLearning is not a known collection for ExampleData. Use ExampleData[] for a list of collections`

However, when running `ExampleData[]`, one see that `MachineLearning` belongs to the collection of example data.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm on version 12.3.1, Mac OS 10.15.7

Comment: Copy pasted your command and it runs fine on Win7, v12.2.0

Comment: OK in 12.3.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: I get : `"FisherIris" is not a known entity for the collection "MachineLearning". Use ExampleData["MachineLearning"] for a list of 
entities`...

Comment: @Syed & user64494, thanks. Would be nice to have feedbacks from mac users :)

Comment: Run this please: `ExampleData["MachineLearning"]` :  I get `{{"MachineLearning", "BostonHomes"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "FisherIris"}, {"MachineLearning", "MNIST"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "MovieReview"}, {"MachineLearning", "Mushroom"}, {"MachineLearning",
   "Satellite"}, {"MachineLearning", "Titanic"}, {"MachineLearning", 
  "UCILetter"}, {"MachineLearning", "WineQuality"}}`

Comment: I get : `$Failed`

Comment: Maybe there is some package to load...

Comment: Check `Edit-> Preferences -> Internet and Mail` There is a checkbox for "Allow the Wolfram system to access the internet". This data will have to be downloaded prior to first use (at least that is my understanding of it).

Comment: @Sayed, it is already checked. I have tested internet connectivity, it's just fine !

Comment: OK, I found ! One has to check the button : `Verify automatically data upgrades`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sayed to show me the right search direction :)